# Iptables accepts any ip or range in any format

Tags: linux, iptables-persistent

Update Jun 30
I have a list of ips.txt and I want iptables accepts any ip or range in any format. Example:

```
# IPs List
199.59.243.120
157.60.1.0/24
91.190.0.0/16
192.168.2.1-192.168.2.25
```

My rule:

```
for ip in $(sed '/#.*/d' ips.txt); do
   if echo $ip | grep -q "-" >/dev/null; then
     iptables -w -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m iprange --dst-range "$ip" -j ACCEPT
   else
     iptables -w -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -d $ip -j ACCEPT
   fi
done
```

Iptables accept the ip 199.59.243.120 and the range 192.168.2.1-192.168.2.25, but how to get iptables accept the range 157.60.1.0/24 or 91.190.0.0/16???

Thanks

Comment: for range to work , you cant give it a network address , but u need to give it a range like 157.60.1.1-157.60.1.254. therefore , first convert all the CIDR formates to ranges like that and then run it.

Comment: I updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `iptables -d` accepts networks in CIDR notation, you can probably just change your `grep` to finding ranges specified with a `-` and then swap your commands (or negate the result from grep).

Comment: I updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

157.60.1.0/24 lies in else condition like -d 157.60.1.0/24 -j  Accept.It do not fit in first condition --dst-range as the error says.
So command is 
echo $ ip l grep -q "-"

Comment: I updated the question for clarity.